# Paypal grid view only send first column instead of every column

Tags: c#, button, gridview, paypal, payment

I have a button which is to send all items that has been added into the grid view into the pay pal site. Currently, it only send the first column of item into the paypal site. For example, I have item A and item B in the shopping cart. Only item A information will go to the paypal site while not item B. Please help me. Thanks and Best regards!:D

Grid view code:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gv_CartProduct" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" onRowCommand="gv_CartProduct_OnRowCommand">
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_title" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label> 
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">                   
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="imgPreview" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image")  %>' runat="server"
                            Height="80px" Width="80px" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="Price" DataFormatString="{0:0.00}" />
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
       <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_quantity" runat="server"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("title")%>' Text='<%# Eval("qty") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="deleterow" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("title") %>' OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete product?');"  ></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

btn_checkout_Click code:

```
 protected void btn_Checkout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CartBLL cbll = new CartBLL();
            Cart c1 = new Cart();
            username = (string)(Session["username"]);


            foreach (GridViewRow row in gv_CartProduct.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {

                    string qtystring = ((TextBox)(row.FindControl("tb_quantity"))).Text;
                    string title = ((Label)row.FindControl("lbl_title")).Text;
                    int amount = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Text);
                    string amountInString = amount.ToString();



                    string redirectUrl = "";

                    //Mention URL to redirect content to paypal site
                    redirectUrl += "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paypalemail"].ToString();

                    //First name I assign static based on login details assign this value
                    redirectUrl += "&first_name=" + username;

                    //Product Name
                    redirectUrl += "&item_name=" + title;

                    //quantity
                    redirectUrl += "&quantity=" + qtystring;

                    //Business contact paypal EmailID
                    redirectUrl += "&business=121366S-facilitator@mymail.nyp.edu.sg";

                    //price if any, or available or using shopping cart system
                    redirectUrl += "&amount=" + amount;



                            //If transactioin has been successfully performed, redirect SuccessURL page- this page will be designed by developer
                redirectUrl += "&return=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SuccessURL"].ToString();

                //If transactioin has been failed, redirect FailedURL page- this page will be designed by developer
                redirectUrl += "&cancel_return=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FailedURL"].ToString();

                Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
               }
            }
        }
```